# Conditionally set a Stash value

Tags: stash, conditionals, switchee

I'm using Stash to set a value like so;

```
{exp:stash:set_value name="head_title" value="{title}"}
```

However, I have now added a new channel field {news_meta_title} and would like to pass this as the value of "head_title" if it has been entered, otherwise just use {title}.

I have tried doing this, but it didn't work;

```
{if news_meta_title}
    {exp:stash:set_value name="head_title" value="{news_meta_title}"}
{if:else}
    {exp:stash:set_value name="head_title" value="{title"}
{/if}
```

I was wondering if anyone had any pointers?

I know that it's all down to parse order, but not sure on how to resolve this.

Comment: We need to lobby Croxton for the addition of a `default` parameter on the various set tags...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is in fact a `default=""` parameter available for Stash set, however it only comes into play if you define a match parameter to test the value being set against a regular expression:

Thus this will do what you want:

```
{exp:stash:set name="head_title" match="#^\S+#" default="{title}"}{news_meta_title}{/exp:stash:set}
```

One problem with this approach however is that if you pass a variable as a default value (e.g. `{title}`) - and that value contains double quotes - that will blow up the parameters and throw a template parse error.

Switchee provides a simple way around this problem because you can pass a *reference* to the Stash variable to evaluate (rather than the variable value itself) by prefixing the name with `stash:`

```
{exp:stash:set name="head_title"}{news_meta_title}{/exp:stash:set}

{exp:switchee variable="stash:head_title" parse="inward"}
    {case value=""}
        {exp:stash:set name="head_title"}{title}{/exp:stash:set}
    {/case}
{/exp:switchee}
```

Alternatively, blocks allow you to provide a fallback value when you *get* the variable - this can be useful if alternative markup is required when the default value is used:

For example:

```
{exp:stash:set name="head_title"}{news_meta_title}{/exp:stash:set}
{exp:stash:set name="entry_title"}{title}{/exp:stash:set}

{exp:stash:block name="head_title"}
    {!-- fallback value if "head_title" is empty --}
    {exp:stash:entry_title}
{/exp:stash:block}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much Mark. I'll give this a try.

Comment: Hey Mark, when I used the Switchee method it broke the page and ended up showing a lot of EE tags instead of content. When I used the Block method, this worked. however, when I then removed the meta title from the entry to test - the page still showed the meta title. Is this just to do with caching?

Comment: Bingo. I tried the switchee method again after realising that because my use case required the switchee to be nested so I just needed to remove the 'exp:' from the opening and closing tags.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could wrap that whole block with `{exp:stash:parse process="end"} ... {/exp:stash:parse}` to make it all parse at the end.  Like this

```
{exp:stash:parse process="end"}
    {if news_meta_title}
        {exp:stash:set_value name="head_title" value="{news_meta_title}"}
    {if:else}
        {exp:stash:set_value name="head_title" value="{title"}
    {/if}
{/exp:stash:parse}
```

Mark's docs are [here](https://github.com/croxton/Stash/wiki/%7Bexp%3Astash%3Aparse%7D).

Comment: Thanks Scott. For some reason it just outputs the field name rather than the content of the field. :/

Comment: Ah, then perhaps it's time for some [switchee](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/switchee) magic.

Answer (score 1):

I **think** this might be due to using an advanced conditional, which I guess could result in parse order issues.

Maybe this would work:

```
{if news_meta_title}
    {exp:stash:set_value name="head_title" value="{news_meta_title}"}
{/if}
{if news_meta_title == ""}
    {exp:stash:set_value name="head_title" value="{title}"}
{/if}
```

If not, have you tried adding `parse="inward"` as Mark mentions in the [documentation](https://github.com/croxton/Stash/wiki/%7Bexp%3astash%3aset_value%7D)?

Alternatively, you could try this set-up instead, which works for me:

```
{exp:stash:set name="head_title" parse_conditionals="yes"}
    {if news_meta_title}
      {news_meta_title}
    {/if}
    {if news_meta_title == ""}
       {title}
    {/if}
{exp:stash:set}
```

Comment: Thanks Katrin, not sure why it won't work for me. It displays correct if there is a meta title entered, but if the field is empty then it won't show the title.

Comment: What happens if you do this: `{exp:stash:set name="head_title" parse_conditionals="yes"} {title} {exp:stash:set}`? Does the title show then? Without knowing the rest of your template code and set-up, it's hard to pinpoint where the issue could lie.

Comment: edited above to close `{title}`. that might be your issue now.

Comment: Well spotted Stephen!